# Calculating a series

Tags: java

I am trying to write a program that accepts an integer from the user, then it should calculate this series **S = 1/2! - 1/3! + 1/4! – 1/5! + ....** all the way to **1/x!** where **x** is the integer taken from the user, I already wrote this code to calculate the factorial of **x** :

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Factorial {

    public static void main(String args[]){

        Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
        int number = x.nextInt();
        int fact = 1;

        for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++){
            fact = fact*i;
        }

        System.out.println("The factorial of "+number+" is "+fact);
        x.close();
    }
}
```

but still am not sure how to code the series, any tips would be really appreciated.

Also I am sorry if my code is not organized I don't know how to use stackoverflow tools ;( .

Comment: You're on the right track. One step would be to create a function, called factorial, which takes an integer as an argument. Then create another function, series, which also takes an int argument. You'll need a loop inside series that calls factorial. Once you code series and factorial, we can help you, especially if you tell us what you expected and what you're getting instead.

Comment: Note that an `int` can't hold more than 12!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, what you want is to separate your code into multiple functions, and think logically.

Since you said you didn't want tips, I'll just try to put you on the right track.

---

**Tip 1:**

Separate your code into multiple functions

eg.

```
public static int factorial(int n){
   int fact = 1;

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        fact = fact*i;

    }
    return fact;
}
```

This allows you to split your code up into manageable chunks. Call each chunk at the appropriate time. This makes your code easier to read and more reusable

---

**Tip 2:**

One main class and the other class with functions.

Ideally, you want to create two classes, one which takes input from the user and one which contains all the functions you need. The main class taking the input will create an Object of the other class

```
public class Factorial{
    public static void main(String args[]){

    Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
    int number = x.nextInt();
    Series s=new Series(number);
    s.print();
    x.close();
}
```

And in **Series.java**

```
public class Series{
   int output;
   int input;

   Series(int i){
      input=i;
      //..here you calculate output
   }
   public int factorial(int n){
        //.... the code 
   }

  public void print(){
     System.out.println("The calculation of " + input + " is " + output);
  }


}
```

---

**Tip 3:**

Make a nice simple function to calculate the output. Sum up all your factorials over time

```
 for (int i = 2; i <= input; i++) {
        //if its even
        if(i%2==0)
           output = output + 1.0 / factorial(i);
        else
           output = output - 1.0 / factorial(i);
 }
```

Add the following to your constructor and you'll have a well built Java program

---

**Tip 4:**: These sums are going to be decimals, not integers so you need to replace all your `int`s with `double`s

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to compute **a sum of terms**. The standard pattern is like

```
double sum = 0;
for (int i = first; i <= last; i++) {
   sum += term(i);
}
```

then remark that

1. the first term is term(2) = +1/2!
2. the second term is term(3) = -1/3! = -term(2)/3
3. the third term is +1/4! = -term(3)/4
4. etc.

So you'll notice that each term can be easily obtained from the previous one.

This leads to

```
double sum = 0;
double term = (some value);
for (int i = first; i <= last; i++) {
   term = (some expression involving i and previous term);
   sum += term;
}
```

Exercise left as, huh, an exercise ?